# What is the significance of this line in my Install4J log?

Tags: windows, install4j

We are attempting to install a product on Windows 7, 64-bit machine. The installer was built with Install4J. The installer eventually fails. I noticed the first line in i4j_nlog1.log is this:

```
[0:0] restrict DLL directories
```

What is the significance of this line and what is the logic surrounding this message?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This refers to a mechanism that prevents DLL hijacking. DLL hijacking is an attack vector for viruses where a system DLL is placed into the download directory. Instead of loading the system DLL from the usual directory, an installer loads the infected library. After the user grants the installer elevated privileges, the virus can take over the system.

The message is likely not related to the failure of your installer.